# Asp.net object reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

In asp.net web application I get this error when populating `datalist` from database.
In design page I have some labels inside an item-template tag,  when I try to access these labels by `FindControl` it gives the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of object

here is my code:

**Products.aspx.cs:**

```
    public partial class Products : System.Web.UI.Page
    {                    
        Product product;             

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            if (!IsPostBack)
                DataList1.DataBind();
            product = this.getProducts();

            Label TitleLabel = (Label)DataList1.FindControl("TitleLabel");
            TitleLabel.Text = product.Name;    

            Label DescLabel = (Label)DataList1.FindControl("DescLabel");
            DescLabel.Text = product.LongDescription;    

            Label PriceLabel = (Label)DataList1.FindControl("PriceLabel");
            PriceLabel.Text = product.UnitPrice.ToString();    

            ImageButton PImage = (ImageButton)DataList1.FindControl("ImageButton1");
            PImage.ImageUrl = "images/"+product.ImageFile;                     
        }    

        private Product getProducts()
        {
            Product p = new Product();

            DataView productsTable = (DataView)
            SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

            foreach (DataRowView row in productsTable)
            {    
                p.ProductID = row["P_Id"].ToString();
                p.Name = row["Title"].ToString();
                p.ShortDescription = row["Desc"].ToString();
                p.LongDescription = row["Desc_full"].ToString();
                p.UnitPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Price"]);
                p.ImageFile = row["imageurl"].ToString();                                
            }                      
            return p;    
        }
    }
```

**Products.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Products.aspx.cs" Inherits="ECProject.Products" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="P_Id" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RepeatColumns="4" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"  >
            <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775"  />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <ItemStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <ItemTemplate >

                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  Height = "200px"/>
                <br />

                Title:
                <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
                <br />                   

                Brand:
                <asp:Label ID="DescLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Desc") %>'  />
                <br />                                      

                Available:
                <asp:Label ID="Is_ActiveLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Is_Active") %>' />
                <br />    

                 Price:
                <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>' />
                   <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        </asp:DataList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ECDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" 
            ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Product]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>        
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error:**

```
Line 25:             
Line 26:             Label TitleLabel = (Label)DataList1.FindControl("TitleLabel");
Line 27:             TitleLabel.Text = product.Name;
Line 28: 
Line 29:
```

Please help, how to get rid of this error ?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 3):

The list usually contains more than one item, so your logic is flawed. What you can do it handle the `ItemDataBound` event of the list by adding such line in your `Page_Load`:

```
DataList1.ItemDataBound += new DataListItemEventHandler(DataList1_ItemDataBound);
```

And have such method:

```
void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Label TitleLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("TitleLabel");
        TitleLabel.Text = "changed by code";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To customize your individual DataList items, you need to do it in the ItemDataBound event. Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y92e1ze%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tutorial for more details.

However, it looks like you are approaching your task in an incorrect manner. Bottom line is that you need to bind your DataSource to a collection of items, and you are trying to feed it items one-by-one. Let me know if I misunderstood you and you do need to bind an individual Product to your DataList customizing its appearance at bind time.

Answer (score 0):

I think your lable put in other object same as panel. you should find the real name of your lable in html code, so the best way is putting a mistake error in you script code as a result when your solution is runnig it will stop and you can find the real name of your lable control. Then use below code :

Label TitleLabel = (Label)DataList1.FindControl("REAL NAME OF LABEL CONTROL");

I hope it can help you.